# Can I expect browsers to cache static content served over SSL encryption?

Tags: https, browsers, cache, static-content, cache-control

With all the talk about [FireSheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep) I am thinking of switching my web applications to use full https accross the entire site. However, I am concerned about caching. I use a lot of JavaScript, CSS files, images, and other static content that I expect the browser to cache. If it doesn't that could mean significant delays for users.

Is there a way to get browsers to cache static content served via SSL? Will the `cache-control: public` HTTP header help? How do the different browsers handle this? Do they never cache the data? Do they cache for a single browser session?

I don't want to serve the static content from an unsecured connection if that means some browsers will put up the warning that some resources are not secure. Is there an alternative solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https) tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to say that FF3+ and IE will do it if that header is set. Earlier versions of FF only cache for the browser's session (in-memory). What about Opera, Safari, Konqueror, and Chrome?